# ARC implementation of self property while passing it to block

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

I have shifted to ARC recently and had a little confusion regarding setting the correct property value for a self object while passing it to a block.

In my understanding, any property declared with **_*weak*** should not be set to nil in dealloc method. And self objects passed to a block should be declared with **_weak** and not **__block**.

Please let me know if this understanding is correct and I am doing it the right way in the below implementation.

```
(void)myApplication {
    self.data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    __weak MyViewController *aBlockSelf = self;

    [self.data setValue:[MyAction customActionWithBlock:^(MyAction *iAction, NSString *iIdentifier) {
    AnotherViewController *aController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithType:@"aType"];
    aController.hasSearch = NO;
    aController.delegate = aBlockSelf;
        aController.showInventoryImage = YES;
    [aBlockSelf presentNavigationalModalViewController: aController];

    }] forKey:@"aKey"];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my understanding, any property declared with `__weak` should not be set to `nil` in `dealloc` method.

Yep, there's absolutely no reason why you'd ever want to do that. It's not a problem, but it achieves nothing.

> And self objects passed to a block should be declared with `__weak` and not `__block`.

Yes, in ARC, using `__weak` mitigates the risk of retain cycles (a.k.a. strong reference cycle). This is important when saving the block to some variable, like in your example, or if the block is running asynchronously. See [Avoid Strong Reference Cycles when Capturing self](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW16) in the *Programming with Objective-C* guide.

> Please let me know if this understanding is correct and I am doing it the right way in the below implementation.

My only suggestion in your code block is that you'd generally see a variable named `weakSelf` for this purpose, rather than `aBlockSelf`. Not a big deal, but it makes the code a little more self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is correct.

```
__weak MyViewController *aBlockSelf = self;
```

Also, when using ARC, you shouldn't be overriding `dealloc`, unless you created and are maintaining references to Core Foundation objects. When you do override `dealloc`, don't call `[super dealloc]`.

Comment: I would say there are a lot more reasons than that to override dealloc!